# Have any producers commented on what would be done with Chekov?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot

Certainly, it is very much unclear if there will ever be another Kelvin-timeline *Star Trek* movie.

But the death of [Anton Yelchin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Yelchin) would leave a quandary for the character of Chekov in any such film.   The obvious choices would be:

- recast
- death
- reassignment
- limited reuse of existing footage
- digital recreation?   (unlikely)

##### Has any likely member of the production or writing staff of a future *Star Trek* film commented on what treatment they would give to the character of Chekov?

Comment: Transferred to the Reliant would be the obvious choice.

Comment: Why don't they just the get guy who played Chekov in _Star Trek: Renegades_.

Comment: The character of Chekov is clearly superhuman. He held onto two or three crewmen over a railing with one arm (at least 350 pounds)! With that sort of strength feat, the writers could justifiably claim that he “evolved” into an energy being, as John Doe does in TNG’s “Transfigurations.”

Comment: “it is very much unclear if there will ever be another Kelvin-timeline Star Trek movie” — is it? Seems a decent bet that [there will be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Beyond#Sequel).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   It still seems uncertain to me until that is solidified.   Lot of projects don't get past that stage.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That wiki reference is out of date. Currently there's still no decision made. http://au.ign.com/articles/2018/01/07/chris-hemsworth-reveals-the-status-of-star-trek-4-after-tarantino-rumors

Comment: @ThePopMachine: sure, I agree it’s uncertain. But they’ve been making Star Trek movies for 40 years, and the last one wasn’t a disaster. I’ll bet dollars to donuts there’ll be another one.

Comment: @Tim: it’s not particularly out of date — it says a writer got hired less than a month ago. That doesn’t mean a movie will be made, but all your reference says is that when someone asked Chris Hemsworth the other day, he said he hasn’t heard anything.

Answer (score 11):

J. J. Abrams [has explicitly stated](http://torontosun.com/2016/07/14/jj-abrams-star-trek-wont-replace-anton-yelchin/wcm/5e24bcff-332b-435a-8e8a-9962a61cd87b) that the part will *not* be recast.

> “I would say there’s no replacing him. There’s no recasting. I can’t possibly imagine that, and I think Anton deserves better,” Abrams said.

However, how the character's absence will be handled is unclear at this stage.

> Is the character of Chekov himself going to be killed off? “I have thought about it, we’re working on it, and it’s too early to talk about it,” he [Abrams] said.

Comment: They recast Dumblebore when Richard Harris died so they can do the same for this role and any other actor that has died before the next film in a series.

Comment: @dean1957 The difference is that Dumbledore is pretty central to the books and removing the character from the films would have been very strange for the fans. In ST, while Chekhov and other secondary characters are loved by fans, the only absolutely necessary characters are Kirk, Spock and McCoy.

Comment: @HorusKol, well, plus the plot of future *Star Trek* movies isn't predetermined.

Comment: @ThePopMachine indeed